# Calculate the time difference between two columns in time format hh:mm:ss

Tags: linux, awk, sed, rhel, perl

I want the time difference between column 5 & column 4

My Input:

```
DATE       TIMESTAMP  ID   START TIME END TIME
2019-04-05 13:57:19   1607 13:06:42   13:07:12
2019-04-05 13:58:00   2327 13:57:26   13:57:43
```

OUTPUT Required:

```
DATE       TIMESTAMP  ID   START TIME END TIME  TIME DIFFERENCE
2019-04-05 13:57:19   1607 13:06:42   13:07:12  00:00:30
2019-04-05 13:58:00   2327 13:57:26   13:57:43  00:00:17
```

### CODE USED:

```
awk '
function convert(t) {

    split(t,Arr,":")
    return Arr[1]*3600+Arr[2]*60+Arr[3]

}
/^#/ {print $0,"\ttotal(sec)"; next}
{print $0,"\t",convert($5)-convert($4) }'
```

---

OUTPUT OF CODE:

```
DATE       TIMESTAMP  ID    START TIME END TIME    TIME DIFFERENCE
2019-04-05 13:57:19   1607  13:06:42   13:07:12       30
2019-04-05 13:58:00   2327  13:57:26   13:57:43       17
```

Output of above given command is in seconds , i need the output in HH:MM:SS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk '
function convert(t) {

    split(t,Arr,":")
    return Arr[1]*3600+Arr[2]*60+Arr[3]

}
function HMS(sec){
hr=int(sec/3600)
min=int(sec/60-hr*60)
sec=sec-(hr*3600+min*60)

return sprintf("%02d:%02d:%02d",hr,min,sec)
}
/^#/ {print $0,"\ttotal(sec)"; next}
{print $0,"\t",HMS(convert($5)-convert($4)) }'
```

Comment: Worked , Solved